# show checkbox checked value =='Y' else unchecked

Tags: angular

I want to display checkbox checked if value =='Y' else unchecked
I have tried the following code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6jewe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let name of names">
          <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="name.checked == 'Y' ? name.checked = 'N' : name.checked = 'Y'" [checked]="name.checked == 'Y'" [name]="name.id + '_checkbox'"></td>
          <td>{{name.id}}</td>
          <td>{{name.name}}</td>
          <td>{{name.Initial}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.remark" [disabled]="name.checked == 'Y'"  [name]="name.id+ '_remark'"></td>
        </tr>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym1rda?file=src/app/app.component.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="name.checked == 'Y'"  [name]="name.id + '_checkbox'">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tot5bs?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks@Adrita Sharma , but with  [(ngModel)]="name.checked" in it. it is not working.

Comment: It won't. To make it work, it should have boolean value

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="name.checked=='Y'"
        (ngModelChange)="name.checked=$event?'Y':'N')">
```

And

```
[disabled]="name.checked!='Y'"
```